# One-sided T-test using np.var and np.sqrt (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, standard-deviation, t-test

This is the exercise:
For both of these exercise, you get two lists of values that you want to compare. You will have
to calculate the variance and the means, then compare them according to the t-test.

Suppose a researcher is studying the effect of a new medication on blood pressure. They
measure the blood pressure of 20 participants before and after taking the medication, and
want to know if the medication lowers blood pressure. The null hypothesis is that the
medication has no effect on blood pressure. The alternative hypothesis is that the medication lowers blood pressure. Conduct a one-sided t-test to determine if the medication is
effective at lowering blood pressure. Use a significance level of 0.05.
– Before the medication: 118, 126, 132, 142, 136, 125, 130, 140, 128, 134, 138, 127, 131,
129, 139, 124, 133, 137, 141, 135
– After the medication: 116, 102, 125, 144, 107, 123, 118, 131, 145, 111, 134, 137, 128,
121, 142, 119, 135, 129, 139, 126

I have three questions:

1. Is it right that I calculate the variance with the difference between both arrays [as indicated by the lecture I attend] (because my intuition tells me that I should use the mean difference, ergo mean_after_med - mean_before_med)?
2. Calculating var_med with np.var(med_diff, ddof=1), does it imply that med_diff is divided by n-1 (bcs of ddof=1) by numpy itself? Albeit the confusing documentation on this, I do believe it does that afaik (this is also what I assume for the third question)
3. Presuming that var_med = np.var(med_diff, ddof=1) is correct, do I need to divide the variance by n again under the square root? In my case, the prof has written it like this: s = np.sqrt(var_med/n). However, I thought just taking the square root of the variance is enough, without dividing by n again. Could somebody confirm this please?

Disclaimer: I know that there are different modules to do a t-test or to calculate the std with numpy but the prof wants it somehow like this, Computer Linguists, sikes.

This is my code (where I use var_med = np.var(med_diff, ddof=1) and s = np.sqrt(var_med/n):

````
#H0: The medication has no effect on blood pressure
#H1: The medication lowers blood pressure

#Before the medication


before_med = np.array([118, 126, 132, 142, 136, 125, 130, 140, 128,
                       134, 138, 127, 131, 129, 139, 124, 133, 137, 141, 135])

#After the medication
after_med = np.array([116, 102, 125, 144, 107, 123, 118, 131, 145,
                      111, 134, 137, 128, 121, 142, 119, 135, 129, 139, 126])

print(len(before_med), len(after_med))

n = len(before_med)


mean_before_med = np.mean(before_med)
print('Mean before medication:', mean_before_med)
mean_after_med = np.mean(after_med)
print('Mean after medication:', mean_after_med)


#Compare them according to the t-test

#Difference between both arrays
med_diff = after_med-before_med


#var_med = np.var(med_diff, ddof=1)
#Numpy's var function uses n as divisor as a default but when ddof is set to 1, it uses n-1 as divisor
var_med = np.var(med_diff, ddof=1)
print("Varianz", var_med)

s = np.sqrt(var_med/n)
#or s = np.sqrt(var_med)
print("Standard deviation", s)


df = n-1
tval = (mean_after_med-mean_before_med)/s
print("Tval", tval)

pval = t.cdf(tval, df=df)

print("t-value=", tval, "p-value=", pval)
#The p value obtained from the one sample t-test is significant
#(p < 0.05), and therefore, we conclude that the average diameter of the
#balls in a random sample is equal to 5 cm.

#Result: Since the p-value is significant, the medication lowers blood pressure -> reject H0

#the value that separates 0.05 (thus, 5%) of the data from 95%

sep = t.ppf(0.95, df)
print("the value that separates 0.05 (thus, 5%) of the data from 95%", sep)```
````

Comment: btw the imports are: ````from scipy.stats import t
import numpy as np````

Comment: If you are about to use scipy stats, then definitely use tests from the package.